# Slick Slider CSS transition bug with infinite loop

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, infinite-loop, slick.js

I have implemented a multi-layered carousel slider with slick.js. It's working nicely except for one transition issue. When it starts the loop, the first and last carousel slider transition doesn't work smoothly.

`Slider link`: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Zihad24/pen/RwyZBxb)

I have added a total of 5 sliders and when the 6th slider comes with a loop, it's lost the smooth transition.

Please check the slider in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Zihad24/pen/RwyZBxb) and suggest to me if you have any.

Thanks in advance!!

`Screenshot correct:` [Correct one with transition](https://prnt.sc/9PLsk8FpObxc)

`Screenshot incorrect:` [Incorrect one which not getting CSS transition on loop](https://prnt.sc/c11tUn_ixhyF)

Comment: Follow the rules for inserting screenshots in the question -> [screenshots guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post)   |   Also follow rules for inserting code in your post -> [code snippets guide](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)